# Spree: additional_tax_total = nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

The error occurs when adding a product to the cart:

```
TypeError at /orders/populate
nil can't be coerced into Float
```

Coming from spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/item_adjustments.rb:

```
  item.update_columns(
    :promo_total => promo_total,
    :included_tax_total => included_tax_total,
    :additional_tax_total => additional_tax_total,
    :adjustment_total => promo_total + additional_tax_total,
    :updated_at => Time.now,
  )
```

I have traced the issue to these two lines of code in `item_adjustments.rb`:

```
included_tax_total = tax.is_included.reload.map(&:update!).compact.sum
additional_tax_total = tax.additional.reload.map(&:update!).compact.sum
```

I am able to get around the issue by setting both to 0, but I'm sure I don't *want* to do this:

```
included_tax_total = 0
additional_tax_total = 0
```

Gem versions:

```
gem 'spree', git: 'git@github.com:spree/spree', branch: '2-4-stable'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '2-4-stable'
```

Instance Variable @item

```
#<Spree::LineItem id: nil, variant_id: 1, order_id: 4, quantity: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:c159b70,'0.1599E2',18(27)>, created_at: "2015-02-06 18:45:26", updated_at: "2015-02-06 18:45:26", currency: "USD", cost_price: #<BigDecimal:8d3d030,'0.17E2',9(18)>, tax_category_id: 1, adjustment_total: #<BigDecimal:c0035a0,'0.0',9(18)>, additional_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:c003578,'0.0',9(18)>, promo_total: #<BigDecimal:c003550,'0.0',9(18)>, included_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:c003528,'0.0',9(18)>, pre_tax_amount: #<BigDecimal:c003500,'0.0',9(18)>>
```

Longer error:

```
Started POST "/store/orders/populate" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-05 22:16:49 -0600
Processing by Spree::OrdersController#populate as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tnscLkBcDAlPkPEq5xMZJDmSf90j+Sb3IXvIlmSOk64=", "variant_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"1", "button"=>""}
  Spree::Preference Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `spree_preferences`.* FROM `spree_preferences`  WHERE `spree_preferences`.`key` = 'spree/frontend_configuration/locale' LIMIT 1
  Spree::Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `spree_orders`.* FROM `spree_orders`  WHERE `spree_orders`.`number` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Spree::Store Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `spree_stores`.* FROM `spree_stores`  WHERE (url like '%localhost%')  ORDER BY `spree_stores`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Spree::Store Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `spree_stores`.* FROM `spree_stores`  WHERE `spree_stores`.`default` = 1  ORDER BY `spree_stores`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Spree::Order Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `spree_orders`.* FROM `spree_orders`  WHERE `spree_orders`.`completed_at` IS NULL AND `spree_orders`.`currency` = 'USD' AND `spree_orders`.`guest_token` = 'LO_p_oGy-8D5dy-J84tizA' AND `spree_orders`.`store_id` = 1 AND `spree_orders`.`user_id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `spree_orders`.* FROM `spree_orders`  WHERE `spree_orders`.`completed_at` IS NULL AND `spree_orders`.`currency` = 'USD' AND `spree_orders`.`guest_token` = 'LO_p_oGy-8D5dy-J84tizA' AND `spree_orders`.`store_id` = 1 AND `spree_orders`.`user_id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Spree::Order Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `spree_orders`  WHERE `spree_orders`.`number` = 'R794021167' LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `spree_orders`  WHERE (spree_orders.number LIKE 'R794021167%')
  Spree::Order Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `spree_orders`  WHERE `spree_orders`.`number` = BINARY 'R794021167' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `spree_orders` (`created_at`, `currency`, `guest_token`, `number`, `state`, `store_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2015-02-06 04:16:49', 'USD', 'LO_p_oGy-8D5dy-J84tizA', 'R794021167', 'cart', 1, '2015-02-06 04:16:49')
   (2.9ms)  COMMIT
DEPRECATION WARNING: OrderPopulator is deprecated and will be removed from Spree 3, use OrderContents with order.contents.add instead. (called from populate at /home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb:45)
  Spree::Variant Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `spree_variants`.* FROM `spree_variants`  WHERE `spree_variants`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `spree_variants`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Spree::LineItem Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `spree_line_items`.* FROM `spree_line_items`  WHERE `spree_line_items`.`order_id` = 4  ORDER BY spree_line_items.created_at ASC
Unpermitted parameters: currency
  Spree::Price Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `spree_prices`.* FROM `spree_prices`  WHERE `spree_prices`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `spree_prices`.`variant_id` = 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Spree::Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `spree_products`.* FROM `spree_products`  WHERE `spree_products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Spree::TaxCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `spree_tax_categories`.* FROM `spree_tax_categories`  WHERE `spree_tax_categories`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `spree_tax_categories`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  SELECT SUM(`spree_stock_items`.`count_on_hand`) AS sum_id FROM `spree_stock_items` INNER JOIN `spree_stock_locations` ON `spree_stock_locations`.`id` = `spree_stock_items`.`stock_location_id` WHERE `spree_stock_items`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND `spree_stock_items`.`variant_id` = 1 AND `spree_stock_locations`.`active` = 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `spree_line_items` (`cost_price`, `created_at`, `currency`, `order_id`, `price`, `quantity`, `tax_category_id`, `updated_at`, `variant_id`) VALUES (17.0, '2015-02-06 04:16:49', 'USD', 4, 15.99, 1, 1, '2015-02-06 04:16:49', 1)
  Spree::Zone Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `spree_zones`.* FROM `spree_zones`  WHERE `spree_zones`.`default_tax` = 1  ORDER BY `spree_zones`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE 1=0 AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::TaxRate'
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_id` = 6 AND `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_type` = 'Spree::LineItem' AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::TaxRate'
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `spree_orders` SET `spree_orders`.`updated_at` = '2015-02-06 04:16:49' WHERE `spree_orders`.`id` = 4
  Spree::Payment Load (1.9ms)  SELECT `spree_payments`.* FROM `spree_payments`  WHERE `spree_payments`.`order_id` = 4 AND (`spree_payments`.`state` NOT IN ('failed', 'invalid'))  ORDER BY spree_payments.created_at
  Spree::Zone Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `spree_zones`.* FROM `spree_zones`  WHERE `spree_zones`.`default_tax` = 1  ORDER BY `spree_zones`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE 1=0 AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::TaxRate'
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_id` = 6 AND `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_type` = 'Spree::LineItem' AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::TaxRate'
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_id` = 6 AND `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_type` = 'Spree::LineItem' AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::PromotionAction'
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_id` = 6 AND `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_type` = 'Spree::LineItem' AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::PromotionAction' AND `spree_adjustments`.`eligible` = 1  ORDER BY amount ASC, created_at DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_id` = 6 AND `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_type` = 'Spree::LineItem' AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::PromotionAction' AND `spree_adjustments`.`eligible` = 1  ORDER BY amount ASC, created_at DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1  [["adjustable_id", 6], ["adjustable_type", "Spree::LineItem"]]
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_id` = 6 AND `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_type` = 'Spree::LineItem' AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::TaxRate' AND `spree_adjustments`.`included` = 1
  Spree::Adjustment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `spree_adjustments`.* FROM `spree_adjustments`  WHERE `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_id` = 6 AND `spree_adjustments`.`adjustable_type` = 'Spree::LineItem' AND `spree_adjustments`.`source_type` = 'Spree::TaxRate' AND `spree_adjustments`.`included` = 0
   (5.0ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 194ms

TypeError - nil can't be coerced into Float:
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/item_adjustments.rb:63:in `update_adjustments'
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/item_adjustments.rb:18:in `update'
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/line_item.rb:141:in `recalculate_adjustments'
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/line_item.rb:136:in `update_adjustments'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:424:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save!'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/validations.rb:57:in `save!'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `block in save!'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:329:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:273:in `save!'
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/order_contents.rb:84:in `add_to_line_item'
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/order_contents.rb:10:in `add'
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/order_populator.rb:37:in `attempt_cart_add'
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/core/app/models/spree/order_populator.rb:16:in `populate'
   () home/funkdified/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails4.1/bundler/gems/spree-fd575479ca20/frontend/app/controllers/spree/orders_controller.rb:45:in `populate'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:232:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:82:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:73:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:678:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  xray-rails (0.1.14) lib/xray/middleware.rb:37:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.3) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.1.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.3) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  meta_request (0.3.3) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:50:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:26:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:19:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (1.1.0) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.0.3) lib/quiet_assets.rb:23:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:84:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.0.229) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.3) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.2) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:16:in `run'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.1.8) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Anyone have any clues on this one?

Comment: Can you post the outputs for `tax.is_included.reload.map(&:update!)` and `tax.additional.reload.map(&:update!)`?

Comment: Where is the value for `tax` being populated?

Comment: it looks like item.adjustments is returning `[]` and then tax is being called on item.adjustments, which is returning `[]` ... happening here https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-4-stable/core/app/models/spree/item_adjustments.rb

Comment: Looks like your `items` are missing an `Order`. Can you check if there is an order?

Comment: Not sure! Check it out https://gist.github.com/funkdified/ecae54ef109e619d1d9e

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-4-stable/core/app/models/spree/item_adjustments.rb `line 63`:

`:adjustment_total => promo_total + additional_tax_total,`

I notice that `promo_total` is defined in line **48** as:

`promo_total = best_promotion_adjustment.try(:amount).to_f`

My guess would be that `best_promotion_adjustment.amount` value is `null` here. That would explain the error : `nil can't be coerced into Float`.

Comment: Hi thanks for contributing something, but I'm afraid this isn't really solving the problem for me.. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, just my stab at understanding your error.  I'll remove the answer if you like.

Comment: Its ok it might help someone!